# Detect page filename through javascript/php?

Tags: php, javascript, menu, detect

I am making a menu on a Wordpress template and need the menu to detect the current page and highlight it. So for instance, my menu is:

```
<li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
```

So if the user is on the About page, I want that one to have the "class=current". How is this possible? Please appreciate that my javascript/php knowledge is very limited, so kindly make any replies detailed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php variable `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php